# ActionBarSherlock's SherlockDialogFragment style under Gingerbread

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I'm using ActionBarSherlock and a SherlockDialogFragment. When running the app under ICS, the dialog displays nicely. But, when running under Gingerbread, the dialog has no styles applied:

I'm not sure whether this is how it is meant to work or if I am missing something. The ActionBarSherlock only mentions styling an activity to look like a dialog. The sample code has no examples of DialogFragments. My question is: 'Is SherlockDialogFragment supposed to look like a proper dialog under Gingerbread?'

I can't post images because I don't have any reputation points.

Comment: post a link to a picture and I will edit your post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. A `DialogFragment` (and by extension a `SherlockDialogFragment`) is not a UI object and therefore can have no style. What you are referring to is a regular `Dialog` that is being managed by a fragment.
2. ActionBarSherlock does not style `Dialog` elements since they are not part of the action bar. If you want a consistent look to your displayed dialogs you will need to do so yourself.